# Collapse Empty Div in DFP — Problems

Tags: javascript, google-dfp

There's something I'm missing when it comes to collapsing empty divs in DFP. I've put both the code in the header and in the individual ad I'm looking to collapse (the poster ad at the top of the right sidebar), and have disabled serving of any ad when no premium ad runs (so technically nothing should serve). However, the div does not seem to collapse, and leaves an empty space. The site is gearhungry.com

Thanks for any insight you can provide!

Comment: Could you show us some code you're using?

Answer (score 2):

Ad the following to the header section of the ad tag:

googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs(true);

Will collapse all empty divs.

E.g.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
googletag.defineSlot('/test/test1', [320, 50], 'slot1').addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.pubads().enableSyncRendering();
googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
**googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs(true);**
googletag.enableServices();
</script>
```